# Unfortunately HelloAndroid app has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just started working on android apps using eclipse. I created the 'helloWorld' app which I tried to run on an emulator of my own created avd device.

Earlier it was showing 'unfortunately app has stopped', so I tried to resolve it by increasing the Launch Timeout time and it is now 10000 ms. But still it is not resolved.
What should I do? Please help.

My xml file is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="course.examples.helloandroid.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloWorld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and My MainActivity.java file

[image: MainActivity.java]

and this my logcat file :

[image: logCat file]

and this is happening for any avd device instance that I am creating. Please help.

EDIT :
my Manifest.xml file:

[image: Manifest.xml]

Comment: "You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar"; are you aware of doing that?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils : No. Do you know how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes in AVD devices...I would suggest connect a android phone and try with it. It gives you the correct output. Moreover you can also try to put ""hello-world" in android:text="hello world" in the xml file and remove the set method in java file. i hope it helps but do try with an android based device. i had the same problem and it was solved when I used a real device

Comment: thanks but i have been asked to do it using java method only. I have edited my post showing the exception with which it did not work. Can you help me at that ?

Comment: Please show your manifest file also and do you have your appcompat runnning?? and moreover try to make your project clean and run again.. If nothing above works then i would suggest trying using real device...

Comment: as you asked I have posted manifest file images. Please take a look at them. Thanks.

Comment: put android maifest xml file and try cleaning the project and run

Comment: there is a option of androidmanifest.xml file see at the bottom of your screen shot

Comment: I have edited the post again and sorry I did not see that you have asked for xml file. Please take a look now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59467/discussion-between-pooja-gupta-and-ankur-jain).

Comment: you can try putting 11 in the minimum sdk version in the manifest file and did anything happened after cleaning the project???

Comment: No nothing worked. But Now I am trying to create device with target api level 19.